# How to grep all result such that the sub-pattern may or may not containing in the target pattern?

Tags: grep

Suppose I have search the string which give like the following result

```
anything1.knownKeyWord
anything2.knownKeyWord
anything3[1].knownKeyWord
```

How I can write generic syntax for grep such it match all 3 string.
I have done like this

```
^.*\w+\d[\[]?[0]?[\]]?\.knownKeyWord.*$
```

But I think for indexing eg `[1]` is not written in good way, how can I achieve so that even i replace `[1]` with `[2342jdsjf]`, I don't have to change the syntax much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an extended regular expression:

```
$ grep -E '[[:alnum:]_]+[[:digit:]]+(\[[^]]+\])?\.knownKeyWord' <file
anything1.knownKeyWord
anything2.knownKeyWord
anything3[1].knownKeyWord
```

This would extract any line containing a string on the format

```
XXXNNN[YYY].knownKeyWord
```

or

```
XXXNNN.knownKeyWord
```

where `XXX` is any non-empty alphanumeric string (that may also include `_`), `NNN` is any string of  (one or more) digits, and `YYY` is anything not including a `]`.

Use `grep` with `-x` if matches are to be *complete lines*.  Use `-w` if matches are supposed to be complete *words* (i.e. not as a substring of something else).

---

Just using `sed` to show what each part of the regular expression is matching:

```
$ sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]_]+)([[:digit:]]+)(\[[^]]+\])?(\.knownKeyWord)/<\1><\2><\3><\4>/' <file
<anything><1><><.knownKeyWord>
<anything><2><><.knownKeyWord>
<anything><3><[1]><.knownKeyWord>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
grep -w 'knownKeyWord$' file.txt
```

From `man`

> -w, --word-regexp
>
> ```
>           Select  only  those  lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or
>           preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word  constituent  character.   Word-
>           constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
> ```